# Is there a formula translating between sample size formula for single mean between precision and effect size?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, sample-size, paired-data

Let's assume I want to test a paired differences between two samples. Or, equivalently, to check, if the paired mean of differences is statistically non zero.

Now I want to calculate the sample size. There are 2 approaches:

1. using the power. The formula uses the effect size (typically Cohen's D), alpha (significance level) and beta (power = 1-beta). Sometimes it's easier to say "I want to be able to detect at least X effect size"
2. using the precision = half of the confidence interval around the mean. This uses the precision and the alpha (significance level). There's no beta. Sometimes it's easier to say "I want to be able to calculate the CI no wider than X".

But we do we know that confidence interval is naturally linked with p-values. Both use the same test statistic (the same distribution of it). If the CI covers zero, p must be > alpha. If the CI excludes zero, p must be <= alpha.

Thus, I guess there must be some translation between the sample size formula using the power and precision.

Could you, please, provide such transition or a reference, where this is discussed?